# How do I plot a scatterplot with marginal histograms AND histogram of differences using matplotlib and/or seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm looking to augment my scatterplot (Python code, using Matplotlib and/or Seaborn) with marginal distributions (here plotted as histograms, but could also be kernel density estimates):

[image: scatterplot with marginal histograms]

with a visualization of the differences (histogram/density estimate), like so:

[image: scatterplot with histogram of differences]

I could probably roll my own, but this seems like such a common use case that I'm suspecting this might be implemented somewhere already in Matplotlib or Seaborn. A good fifteen minutes of Googling did not yield anything, and it also has not been asked before here on StackOverflow. Does anyone know of an off-the-shelf solution for this? (If no one does, I'll write my own and post it of course.) Thanks!

Comment: There is no built-in command for such rotated histogram. So you would create your custom function that calculates the distance from the diagonal (or whatever quantity) and histogram that quantity. Then you can create a floating axes as in [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/simple_axis_pad.html) or [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/demo_floating_axes.html) example.